# How to get an image from html page to JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp, bufferedimage, fileinputstream

Usually when we try to get text field parameters we write the code as

```
String name = request.getParameter("parameter-name");
```

I am trying to select an image from `<input type="file">` tag and action performed on clicking submit button is page gets redirected to (from_encryption.jsp) page.
From that jsp page i need to get the image which i selected in the html page. I have tried to get the parameters using FileInputStream and BufferedImage,code given below. But it is returning "NULL" value. I am trying to retrieve the image so that i can perform encryption operations. My requirement is not for image uploading. Can anyone tell me how to get the image from the html to jsp page.

HTML code

```
<form action="from_encryption.jsp">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="file" name="Choose1" accept="image/*"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <br><br><input type="submit" name="encrypt" value="ENCRYPT">
    </form>
```

JSP page(from_encryption.jsp)

```
try
        {   
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(request.getParameter("choose1")); 
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fis);

            int height = image.getHeight();
            int width = image.getWidth();
            out.print(height+","+width);


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: is `getParameter` case-insensitive?

Comment: Hai @TomaszKłak.  getParameter("parameter-name") is a predefined method and parameter-name is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thnak you @BalusC, that link helped me in solving the issue